# How to config spring security

Tags: forms, spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying learning how to protect my web Application using Spring security I have some problems, 
this is my web.xml

```
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>loginPage.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>loginPage.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>loginPage.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring context files to be loaded -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!-- filter declaration for Spring Security -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this my spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-processing-url="/login" login-page="/loginPage"
        username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
        default-target-url="/secured/mypage" authentication-failure-url="/loginPage?auth=fail" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutPage" />        
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="srccodes" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

and finally my servlet-dispatcher.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

My application run normally and I have my login page, when I type the right login et password I have error 404 not found!!  with url 
    localhost:8084/LoginFormExampleSpring/secured/mypage

this is my form

```
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

anyone can help me please?

Comment: It seems it has login successfully and tried to open /secured/mypage as per your configuration "default-target-url="/secured/mypage". But it could not find anything ? May be you have not done any mapping for it. What does the server logs says ? Do you have the error stacktrace ?

Comment: I just follow this tuto:
http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/35/spring-security-custom-login-form-example

Comment: Add a breakpoint in SpringSecurityHelloController.java mypage method and debug and see in your IDE. You server log would have useful information, check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add a mapping for /secured/mypage To do so:

- Create a file at /WEB-INF/pages/secured/mypage.jsp
- Add a mvc:view-controller to dispatcher-servlet.xml

For example:

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/secured/mypage"/>
```